# Json decode delete stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json element, I decode it with the function `json_decode($vr)` but like result, it show me this

```
   Array( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [name] => Elis ) 
           [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [name] => Eilbert ))1
```

with that array i can't do nothing, before i have to delete stdClass Object how can i do that?
if i user `json_encode($vr,true)` I'll receive Array instead stdClass.

when i try do the foreach with the json econde it show me a error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string, I thought that is for that stdClass

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: with that array i can't do nothing, before i have to delete stdClass Object how can i do that?

Comment: You want to delete a class? But why? `stdClass` is a native class, I wouldn't mess with it.

Comment: `unset($arr[0]);` if you really want to delete the object, but there is no sense in doing so.

Comment: ok maybe, i don't understand the point, when i try do the foreach with the json econde it show me a error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string, I thought that is for that stdClass

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you need something like that:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $object){

$id = $object->id;
$name=$object->name;

echo "Hello $name your id is $id"; //Or whatever you want to do with it
}

?>
```